# Synonymise [capture-group] with [capturing-group]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Apparently, [capture-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture-group) and [capturing-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capturing-group) are two different tags. Unless there is a difference - which I can't deduce, partly because the former has no description, I suggest to synonymise the tags.

Comment: So to be clear, capturing-group is the tag to keep, right?

Comment: @rene That's what I would suggest, yes.

Comment: Both terms are in common use.  So you'd better propose a synonym instead.

Comment: @HansPassant does it matter which one would be the master?

Comment: It is a [regex] contextual tag, I doubt it matters at all.

Comment: The one which already has a description is probably a better master.