# Synonymise [capture-group] with [regex-group]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Should [capture-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture-group) and [regex-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-group) be synonyms? Should they actually exist at all?

Currently, [capture-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture-group) only has 138 questions, and no watchers. [regex-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-group), however, has 1.4k questions, and 48 watchers.

My opinion is that both of these shouldn't even exist, but since they do, and my guess is that the community consensus is that they're ok, at least they shouldn't be separate: They are about the same concept, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should [capture-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capture-group) and [regex-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-group) be synonyms?

No. **Capture groups are not the only regex groups out there.** While capture groups are commonly used, there are also *non-capture groups* and *atomic groups*. (You can find an outline of regex groups in [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)) Regex groups are more general (as suggested in the tag wiki of [regex-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-group)) while capture groups are more specific (as suggested in the tag wiki of [capturing-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capturing-group)). The situation could also be illustrated with sets.

[image: capture-group is a proper subset of regex-group]

We can translate this to "all capture groups are regex groups but not all regex groups are capture groups". This suggests a non-synonym. If the terms were synonyms, the sets A and B would be equal (to an extent?). But this is not the case here.

> Should they actually exist at all?

Sure, why not? From the [tag help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> > Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into **specific**, **well-defined** categories.
> >
> > **Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.**

<sup>*(emphasis added)*</sup>

Regex groups and capture groups are both specific, well-defined categories. `(so)` is a regex group (assume the parentheses are escaped properly). `\bso\b` isn't a regex group. Well-defined. `(so)` is a capture group. `(?:so)` isn't. Well-defined.

People wanting to know more about regex groups and capture groups can also look up the tags individually. The search becomes more difficult without tags to categorise questions into.

Comment: There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858) answer which explains the regex groups and the capturing groups. And also there are differences in the tag wikis which you should also highlight.

Comment: @double-beep [tag:capture-group] currently has no tag wiki. (I guess that's a difference in itself?) I'm wondering if you were referring to [tag:capturing-group] vs [tag:regex-group] instead.

Comment: Yeah, capture-group and capturing-group appear to be synonyms, since all of the questions are about regex. There's already a meta about it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317673

Comment: Yep, that was a complete mental glitch on my part. After sleeping on it, I woke up expecting a **ton** of downvotes (way more than I actually got). Thanks for the answer!